# Deploy EKS aws without downtime

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

i want to ask how do you deploy with EKS clusters without downtime? Do I have to set min health and max health in the yml file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Helm for deployments,
and you can perform rolling updates with Helm to avoid downtime.

More info [here](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/)

Without using helm you can do a rolling update on a deployment as well.

Kubectl docs have explained it very well, you can follow it here:-

```
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/
```

Comment: without using Helm, can't we apply zero downtime? (ex= update file yml rolling update)

Comment: @elsasyaa
Yes you can do a rolling update on your deployment as well.

I will put a example in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a [rolling update](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/).

Rolling updates allow Deployments' update to take place with zero downtime by incrementally updating Pods instances with new ones. The new Pods will be scheduled on Nodes with available resources